# JqueryUI: trying to show a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
    </script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

and firebug says jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js is loaded.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: 67 questions, 38% acceptance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, [you can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Frj/).

Are you sure you're including the stylesheet for jQuery UI as well?  You either need to include the one that came with your download (and related images in their same relative folders), or use the CDN hosted ones.  You can find the CDN links for 1.7.2 for the various default themes on the jQuery UI blog here: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2009/06/jquery-ui-172/ (under **Google Ajax Libraries API** > **Themes**)

One last thing, as the commenters mention above, you should [accept answers to your questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it'll help you get answers to your future questions quicker.